# Existence of a funcion $T: [2^{\kappa}]^2 \rightarrow \kappa$, containing all partial functions $f$ with $|$dom$(f)| = \kappa$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal. I want to prove that there is a function $T: [2^{\kappa}]^2 \rightarrow \kappa$ with the following property ($[2^{\kappa}]^2$ being the subsets of $2^{\kappa}$ that have 2 elements).
If $f: D \rightarrow \kappa$ is a function where $D \in [2^{\kappa}]^{\kappa}$, then there exists an arbitrarily large $\xi \in 2^{\kappa}$ such that $T(\{\alpha,\xi\}) = f(\alpha), \, \forall \alpha \in D$.
It should follow from the fact that cf$(2^{\kappa}) > \kappa$, so $(2^{\kappa})^{\kappa} = 2^{\kappa}$.
Thanks.

Comment: cf$(2^k)>k$ is a major corollary of Koenig's Theorem (a.k.a.Koenig's Lemma) but it is not needed to prove  that  $(2^a)^b=$ $2^{|a\times b|}=$ $2^{\max (a,b)}$ for all infinite cardinals $a,b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me restate your question: let 
$$P = \bigcup\{{^D}\kappa : D\in [2^\kappa]^\kappa\}.$$
You tried to construct $T:[2^\kappa]^2\to\kappa$ such that the set
$$\{\xi < 2^\kappa \mid T(\{\alpha,\xi\} = f(\alpha)\}$$
has cardinality $\kappa$.

The first observation is $|P|=2^\kappa$; You can check that ${^D}(2^\kappa)$ has cardinality $2^\kappa$ for each $D\in[2^\kappa]^\kappa$. There are $(2^\kappa)^\kappa = 2^\kappa$ subsets of $2^\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$, so the result follows.

Construction of $T$ is now easy: let $\{f_\alpha : \kappa < \alpha < 2^\kappa\}$ be any enumeration of $P$. Take any $\tau : 2^\kappa\to 2^\kappa$ such that for each $\alpha<2^\kappa$ there are $2^\kappa$ ordinals $\xi$ such that $\tau(\xi)=\alpha$. (You can construct such a function by considering a bijection between $2^\kappa$ and $2^\kappa\times 2^\kappa$.

Now define $T(\{\alpha,\beta\})$ as follows:
$$T(\alpha,\beta) = 
\begin{cases}
f_{\tau(\beta)}(\alpha) &\text{if } \alpha <\sup (\operatorname{dom} f_{\tau(\beta)}) < \beta \text{ and } f_{\tau(\beta)}(\alpha) \text{ is defined,}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$
Then $T$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Thanks you!<br/>

Comment: I noticed I made a mistake in my question. It should be $T(\{\alpha,\xi\}) = f(\alpha),\, \forall \alpha \in D$, not $\forall \alpha < \kappa$ like it was. The other thing is that in your definition of $P$, it should be $D \in [2^{\kappa}]^{\kappa}$ instead of $[\kappa]^{\kappa}$, right? If I understand correctly, I can use these new parameters in your proof and it still works.

Comment: @Kling Yes. We need some modification on the answer, but the gist of the proof seems still work.